# systemverilog packages, macros and scope

Tags: scope, macros, package, system-verilog

Im having trouble accessing a package and macro from another library in systenverilog. My undestanding is that a package or macro should be visible within a compilation unit and therefore visible from any library in that unit but that doesn't seem to be the case in this example

> defines.sv

```
`define POUTMAX
```

> mtp_pkg.sv

```
package mtp;
function automatic void set_mtp(string name, int val);
  $display("set_mtp");
endfunction
endpackage
```

> tb.sv

```
module tb;
  initial begin
    mtp::set_mtp("l",7);
//    $display(`POUTMAX);
  end
endmodule
```

If I compile the testbench into its own library the mtp_pkg or macro are not accessible. e.g.

> xrun mtp_pkg.sv defines.sv -makelib tb_lib tb.sv -endlib -top tb

```
file: tb.sv
     mtp::set_mtp("l",7);
       | xmvlog: *E,NOPBIND (tb.sv,6|8): Package mtp could not be bound.
       module tb_lib.tb:sv
               errors: 1, warnings: 0 xrun: *E,VLGERR: An error occurred during parsing.  Review the log file for errors with the code
*E and fix those identified problems to proceed. Exiting with code (status 1).
```

What am I missing here? it seems mtp_pkg is not compiled before tb.sv.
Adding include and or import mtp::* into tb.sv does not fix the problem I then get an error that mtp package exists in 2 places and a binding error.

It works ok if I remove the tb_lib.

Comment: what exactly is the error? can you check the log file as suggested by the message?

Comment: The error is shown above after the compile command: "Package mtp could not be bound" coming from tb.sv line 3 => mtp::set_mtp(...)

Comment: my guess is that you need to put the -makelib around all files which you compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct. Macros are *only* available in the compilation unit where they are defined and not from anywhere else. Packages *must* be compiled before they can be referenced or imported. It seems your script complies `-makelib` files first, so you need to investigate how to ensure they are compiled in the correct order.

Comment: most likely -makelilb marks a compilation unit. It looks like tb.sv and the other files end up in different compilation units.